# jquery on tap fails to change tooltip location in mobile safari

Tags: css, responsive

I have a page with some tooltips that are triggered by mousemove. On mobile, you can tap in the appropriate place to see a tooltip, but then there's no way to get rid of it - it just hangs around. I want them to be able to tap anywhere to discard it. So I tried this:

```
$(document).on('tap',function(){
    $('#tooltip').css("top", -9999);
})
```

Which does... nothing. I have tried a number of variations on this but it bugs me because I feel like this should work. What am I missing?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/szevtb55/

The behavior I want is: mobile user taps on area to see tooltip, then taps anywhere to clear the tooltip.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle example so we can understand what you are really trying to do ?

Comment: I just tested your JSFiddle on my phone and it's functioning as you expect.

Comment: You are missing a unit. What is it? -9999 marbles? -9999 rays of sunshine?

Comment: @connexo That doesn't matter, actually. I had commented something similar and retracted it once I realized that his `mouseover` function doesn't use units either, yet works as intended. See this quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/uhkowfxt/

Comment: Android or iOS Santi? I am testing ios

Comment: Android. Perhaps it's specifically a non-chrome issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is something to do with jquery - I have no idea what. Anyways, this works:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart',function(){
    $('#tooltip').css("top", -9999);
},false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving it 9999 units down why not just remove it?

you can use:

```
.hide();

.remove();

.toggle();
```

or maybe you can add a little x or close button just for mobile and do this:

```
jQuery(".close-button").click(function(){
     jQuery("#tooltip").hide();
});
```

try that. thats the only solution I can think of at the moment I wish I could help more

Comment: this doesn't work either. Pretty sure it's just not detecting the event at all for some reason. Unfortunately Desktop Safari doesn't really emulate touch at all when you do responsive design mode so I don't really know how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: @AustinC check out my updated answer, have you tried creating a close button and hide the tool top on click?

Comment: I really wanted to avoid that solution but maybe I'll give it a shot. If no one has a better idea in a couple days I'll mark this correct.